# How to visualize and convert retrieved OSM buildings data to shapefile?

Tags: openstreetmap, shapefile, geopandas, overpass-api

I have retrieved data from OSM using this script:

```
import overpy
api = overpy.Overpass()
print('Obtaining Data...')
result = api.query("""
[out:json]
[timeout:25]
;
(
  relation
    ["building"]
    (51.909331730124,4.3151378631592,51.954898210091,4.405689239502);
  
    way
    ["building"]
    (51.909331730124,4.3151378631592,51.954898210091,4.405689239502);
);
out;
>;
out skel qt;
""")
```

I would like to visualize the data and save it as a shapefile before performing some spatial analysis. I cannot figure out how to convert/save it as a shapefile, can anyone offer any advice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import osmnx as ox 
import ast

point = 'point coordinates'
dist = 'distance in m'
buildings = ox.geometries.geometries_from_point(point, {'building': True}, dist=dist)
```

And convert to a geodataframe:

```
buildings_save = buildings.applymap(lambda x: str(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
```